# How does zero or more regex operator spare match for end of line?

Tags: regex

The expression `/.*s$/` matches `abcds`. Since `*` is greedy, I expected `.*` to gobble up all characters till and including `s` - which would fail the end of line matcher `s$` part, since the `$` has no characters left. But this matches, how? (I am using ruby 2.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say that `*` is greedy ,  it is greedy in the sense that if there are multiple matches it will prefer the longest one.

But here it there is only one possible match for the regex `/.*s$/` which is '`abcds`'

> Note: The first priority is to to match the full regex against the
>   input.
>
> If there are multiple matches, then only greedy nature of `*` comes
>   into picture

Since Regex is implemented internally through finite Automata.

Here is a detailed explaination through NFA:

This is NFA corresponding to your regex .Note that the third state with inner cirle is the only accepted state here

[image: ]]

Lets track the matching of string "abcds"

After reading 'a'  the state will be :
[image]

After reading 'b' the state will be :
[image]

After reading 'c' the state will be :

[image]

After reading 'd' the state will be :

[image]

After reading 's 'the state will be :[image]'

Note that the automaton shows greedy nature here for `*`

Now it will read end of input
[image]

On reading end of input the automaton cannot go to any of the accepted state.

So the final state non-accepted state.

**Since, this flow did not lead to a accepted state.
the automaton will backtrack**

Back to previous state:

[image]

Now again it will read 's' and look for the possibility of a different path

Which is possible for given automata.

[image]

**Now it will read end of input and Victory!**

[image]

The automaton ends up in a accepted state this time and thus the string "abcds" will be matched.

Comment: The longest one is `abcds` in this case. How does `s$` match?

Comment: does that answer your question?

Comment: Can you cite a reference, or prove with examples, your claim `The first priority...`?

Comment: It explains how regex works, I don't think you can easily find a condensed reference with exactly this statement but it's correct nevertheless.  If a string cannot match, the greediness or absence of same doesn't matter because it never comes into the picture.  In other words, *if* you match governs *how* that match happens.  If you can't match, the "how" doesn't matter.

Comment: Updated the answer . see if this better addresses your query

Answer (score 1):

When `.*` comes, regex engine will match 5 characters `abcds`, until then the next pattern `s` fails to match. So the regex engine **backtracks**. The `.*` now backtracks to 4 matches (`abcd`), giving away the `s`, then the `s` pattern will match the `s`. And lastly the `$`, then the end. Matches `abcds`.

The greedy quantifier `*` will do the backtracks once if the next pattern fails to match.